# BigQuery: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This query was running flawlessly for many months and, out of a sudden, started throwing:
**Scalar subquery produced more than one element**

```
select event_id, user_id, created_at, company_id, message_id, conversation_id, message_text, 'sent' as message_direction, created_at as message_read_at from message_sent

union all

select distinct e.event_id, e.user_id, e.created_at, e.company_id, 
e.message_id, e.conversation_id, 
e.message_text, 'received' as message_direction, 
min(c.created_at) as message_read_at
from message_received e
left outer join conversation_read c on (e.conversation_id=c.conversation_id  and c.created_at > e.created_at)
group by e.event_id, e.user_id, e.created_at, e.company_id, 
e.message_id, e.conversation_id, 
e.message_text, message_direction
```

What could it be?

Comment: Have you tried running the subqueries per separate to analyse the results? 
It is hard to say without the data but my best guess is that the issue is coming from the ```created_at``` fields in the inequality condition of the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: I even removed the join to try and got the same error.. seems like the error is somewhere else.. but as you can see in the code, we are not using any subquery.. that's why I am kinda lost in this.

Comment: That's super strange. Let me see if I understood this correctly. You have: query_1 UNION ALL query_2 .... JOIN .... - I guess you can run query_1 OK, is that right? Same for query_2 ??

Comment: Could you provide the table schema, sample table data and expected result details to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found it after digging further.

It wasn't a problem with this query, but with a view that's used in the query. After debugging the view definition, I figured a problem with its subquery.